# Alternatives to Chrome Apps for access to the local file system

Tags: google-chrome-app

Now that Chrome Apps have been [announced](https://developers.chrome.com/apps/migration) to be kind-of deprecated, what are the alternatives for web programming if one wants to have read-write access to the file system?

Comment: The announcement suggests using Electron or NW.js... Just saying.

Comment: Haven't read this! going to see ...

Comment: Agree with wOxxOm: Electron or NW.js. They are like Chrome Apps in that you build with JavaScript, HTML, CSS, and the rendering is via Chromium. The JavaScript engine is the same, too (Node.js is based on V8.) Obviously versions, packaging, and lots of details are different. A disadvantage of Electron and NW.js is that the executables you distribute are big, since Chromium and V8 are included. (Chrome Apps are exceedingly small.) Personally, I am going with Electron, until and unless I find some stumbling block that causes me to look into NW.js.

Comment: @MarcRochkind Yes, I am algo going with Electron. Sad news I'm using a Chromebook and Electron cannot be used in a Chromebook. Time to change OS I suppose

Comment: Yes, very bad. Soon there will be NO way to write an app that runs on 4 platforms (MacOS, Windows, Linux, ChromeOS).

Comment: @Gerard Google Apps will not be deprecated for Google Chromebooks.

Comment: @MarcRochkind NW.js supports Chrome Apps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you missed it but you can have a [native helper app + extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). You can write some simple cross platform C++/Java binary that allows you to access the file system and have it communicate with your chrome extension. This will cut down file size significantly rather than using other big frameworks. Plus it's relatively simple cross compiling a binary for all major OSs.

> Q: My app uses the chrome.fileSystem API to read and write
>   user-specified files and / or directories. Can this be done on the
>   open web? In general, no. The open web can read single files that the
>   user opens, but cannot retain access to those files, write to those
>   files, or have any access to directories.
>
> If it is critical for your app to read and write directories (e.g. it
>   is a text editor with a folder view), you will need to either have a
>   native helper app and extension combo, or create a native app.

Comment: Any update? (chromeos here)